# Pgfplots contour gnuplot crazy labels

Tags: pgfplots, labels, plot

This is driving me mad. I am tryng to create some contour plots, but I get them full of labels, so that they are unreadable! I can't even see the lines or read the values because they are too much. I just formatted the numeric output from my script, so that the code I am placing here is not really nice. Anyway, I can get the right contour but I would like to have ONLY ONE label on each contour line, not N. I couldn't find any solution on pgfplots manual.
Here is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
         [xlabel=$x$,
         ylabel=$y$,
         width=0.48\columnwidth,
                 view={0}{90},
                 ymin=0, ymax=70
                 ]
        \addplot3
             [contour gnuplot,
                         thick
                         ]
            coordinates {
            .....
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I did not post the coordinates because my file was more than 1000 lines.
Any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Generally, the PGFPlots algorithm does a pretty good job at deciding where to put the labels. If it doesn't work as you want it to, you could try setting `contour/label distance` to a value greater than the default of `200pt`. Maybe you could try creating a smaller sample of your data that reproduces the undesired behaviour, then we could attempt a more targeted solution.

Comment: The automatic label placement of pgfplots only has the `label distance` key to customize its result as indicated by @Jake (however, the initial value is `70pt`). If you only want one label per contour line, you can set `contour gnuplot={label distance=10000pt}`. Pgfplots will always generate one label. You can also disable labels using `contour gnuplot={labels=false}`.

Comment: that worked. Iti didn't post only one label each line but more, anyway result was much better

Answer (score 9):

[answer converted from a comment]

The automatic label placement of pgfplots only has the `label distance` key to customize its result as indicated by @Jake (however, the initial value is `70pt`).

If you only want one label per contour line, you can set `contour gnuplot={label distance=10000pt}`. Pgfplots will always generate one label, so this disables only the following ones.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.7}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        title={$x \exp(-x^2-y^2)$},
        domain=-2:2,enlarge x limits,
        view={0}{90},
    ]
   \addplot3[
        contour gnuplot={
            number=14,
            label distance=10000pt,
        },
        thick]
   {exp(0-x^2-y^2)*x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can also disable labels using `contour gnuplot={labels=false}`.

If you believe that the outcome should be improved somehow (like "move the label somehow" or whatever), you can post feature requests at http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgfplots/ . In that case I would like to ask you to include a full phrase stating the expected behavior.

Comment: thanks for this. On a side node, `label distance=10000pt` works well on *closed contours*. Open contours, e.g. [this](http://imgur.com/ZMB8R5x), makes the labels vanish outside the plot. I tried to use `anchor=south west` and `outer xsep`, but then the labels are sloped wrongly. What could I do? Should I post a question on that?

Comment: That could be a bug. Could you send a minimal working example by mail? My address is in the manual of pgfplots.